# how to save data in stl file after python solid processing?

Tags: python, 3d, openscad

I need to process openscad programs on python. I use solid library (https://solidpython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) but I haven't found any method to save data after process. Example

```
from solid import *
d = difference()(
   cube(10),
   sphere(15)
)
```

I need to save **d** variable to stl file. How to do this? And if there's better library, I need advice what library better to use.

Answer (score 2):

You need openscad to export data as stl-file. You can do this from python-code:

```
from solid import *
# to run  openscad 
from subprocess import run

d = difference()(
   cube(10),
   sphere(15)
)

# generate valid openscad code and store it in file
scad_render_to_file(d, 'd.scad')

# run openscad and export to stl
run(["openscad", "-o",  "d.stl", "d.scad"])
```

instead of last step you can open d.scad in openscad, render it (press F6) and export it as STL or run in console:

```
openscad -o d.stl d.scad
```

the use of openscad from command line see [documentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Using_OpenSCAD_in_a_command_line_environment)