# How to set special variables $fa, $fs, $fn in solidpython

Tags: python, openscad

in [a previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54040390/how-to-save-data-in-stl-file-after-python-solid-processing) is shown, how to create a 3D-body and save it to an stl-file by solidpython. As $fa, $fs, $fn are not set they have the default values and the 3D-body has a low number of facets. 
The example code from the thread above:

```
from solid import *
from subprocess import run

d = difference()(
   cube(10),
   sphere(15)
)

scad_render_to_file(d, 'd.scad')

run(["openscad", "-o",  "d.stl", "d.scad"])
```

Here the resulting stl-body
[image]
In the [documentation](https://solidpython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) i didn‘t find anything about setting these variables. [This readme](https://github.com/bjbsquared/SolidPy/blob/master/readme.md) seems to be obsolete.

How can i set $fa, $fs, $fn in solidpython?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do it.

In solidpython some objects (eg. `circle()`, `sphere()`, `cylinder()`) have the optional parameter `segments` corresponding to `$fn` in openscad, see the source code in the file objects.py in the solidpython package (on archlinux /usr/lib/python/site-packages/solid/objects.py).

possible solidpython code:

```
sphere(15, segments = 180)
```

resulting openscad code:

```
sphere($fn = 180, r = 15);
```

Alternatively a file header can be set in `scad_render_to_file()`,  see the source code in the file solidpython.py in the solidpython package.

solidpython code:

```
scad_render_to_file(d, 'd.scad', file_header = '$fa = 0.1;\n$fs = 0.1;', include_orig_code=True)
```

writes these lines to the top of the openscad file:

```
$fa = 0.1;
$fs = 0.1;
```

and here the resulting stl from the example
[image]