# How do I specify mesh parameters when using OpenSCAD from the Command Line?

Tags: python, command-line, openscad

I am trying to export a ton of simple shapes generated in OpenSCAD and exported as STL files with varying mesh coarse-ness.  I'm using a combination of solidpython and subprocesses to call openscad from the command line but I'm not sure how to use the arguments to specify any of the mesh parameters. I think I have to use the -d argument but I am unsure.

Anything you can offer would be a huge help for me to avoid having to manually save each STL through the GUI.

Comment: if "mesh parameters" means the special variables $fa, $fs, $fn this question already has an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54073851/how-to-set-special-variables-fa-fs-fn-in-solidpython

Answer (score 1):

I have a script and system for doing something similar to this at https://github.com/tinkerology/buildmodels.
It uses a bash script and not python. It could be modified easily to handle your needs.